Identify a Star Trek TNG Episode in which Commander Riker takes control of the Enterprise
I remember an episode where the Enterprise is going to close to a Star.  Commander Riker eventually relieves Picard of command and orders that the Enterprise change course.  Picard had actually been replaced by an alien.  What was the name of the Episode?

Allegiance? http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Allegiance_(episode)

As commented by @Longshanks this is almost certainly Allegiance [Season 3 Episode 18]

Captain Picard and three other people are abducted and imprisoned by an unknown force and replaced by duplicates.


Excerpts...

The Enterprise finally arrives to the Lonka pulsar. Picard then orders to move the ship dangerously close to it, so close that their shields will only last 18 minutes.

...

Picard orders to move even closer to the Pulsar, which would almost certainly destroy the ship. Riker orders to disregard Picard's orders, so Picard commands Worf to remove Riker from the bridge, but Worf does not budge.
Riker takes control of the ship and orders Wesley Crusher to immediately move the Enterprise away from the pulsar.

...

Picard is transported to his ship and the fake Picard is revealed. The Picard clone had been testing if the crew would follow him, even to death.


Thanks Paulie, it is indeed the episode that I'm after with Riker overruling Picard.
